# Веб приложение по расчёту массы детали

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor

Прошу подсказать какой подход лучше применить:

- Лучше использовать чистый js, html/css и ничего больше
- Или использовать mvc, Razor Pages и тп.

Нужно сделать проект по типу как на этом сайте : https://metallicheckiy-portal.ru/calculator/calculator_metalla

Прошу указать соответ. примеры проектов/ развёрнутую литературу.

(месяца 2,5 не прогал на asp.net, изучил asp.net mvc до начальных понятий контролеры модели. Tag-хелперы и прочее не успел доучить, а вот тестовое получил, и не знаю с какой стороны подступить...)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Пишите на том, на чем умеете. Пишите так, чтобы решить поставленную задачу.  Подходы могут быть разные, сравнивать их нет смысла - получится холивар без выводов.

Comment: Вы серьезно? Какая еще развернутся литература? Учебники по физике и геометрии за 8 класс?

Comment: Ответьте сами для себя на простой вопрос: "А нужен-ли для калькулятора, который делает 2+2=4 сервер?" Если ответ "ДА", тогда вам нужен 2-й вариант из вашего списка, ну а как там внутри напишете и при помощи каких подходов, это уже выбор каждого). Ну а если ответ "НЕТ", то вам достаточно простого HTML файлика, который будет иметь определенный вид и через простой JS выполнять конкретную логику (подсчет).